# cannot send data through $http.post methood, getting 500 internal server error

Tags: angularjs, http, post, server, yii2

It has been two hours that I am stuck in this problem, do not know why I am getting this error. The API is written in Yii PHP framework and I am developing the front end. I am getting the error in response which is coming from Yii API.

```
//Create a new Model Action 
public function actionCreate()
{
    switch($_GET['model'])
    {
        // Get an instance of the respective model
        case 'reviewbusinesses':
            $model = new ReviewBusiness;                    
            break;
        default:
            $this->_sendResponse(501, 
                sprintf('Mode <b>create</b> is not implemented for model <b>%s</b>',
                $_GET['model']) );
                Yii::app()->end();
    }
    // Try to assign POST values to attributes
    foreach($_POST as $var=>$value) {
        // Does the model have this attribute? If not raise an error
        if($model->hasAttribute($var))
            $model->$var = $value;
        else
            $this->_sendResponse(500, 
                sprintf('Parameter <b>%s</b> is not allowed for model <b>%s</b>', $var,
                $_GET['model']) );
    }
    // Try to save the model
    if($model->save())
        $this->_sendResponse(200, CJSON::encode($model));
    else {
        // Errors occurred
        $msg = "<h1>Error</h1>";
        $msg .= sprintf("Couldn't create model <b>%s</b>", $_GET['model']);
        $msg .= "<ul>";
        foreach($model->errors as $attribute=>$attr_errors) {
            $msg .= "<li>Attribute: $attribute</li>";
            $msg .= "<ul>";
            foreach($attr_errors as $attr_error)
                $msg .= "<li>$attr_error</li>";
            $msg .= "</ul>";
        }
        $msg .= "</ul>";
        $this->_sendResponse(500, $msg );
    }
}
```

Angular code

```
<form ng-submit="add_review()">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="booking-item-rating">
                                    <ul class="icon-list icon-group booking-item-rating-stars">
                         <input-stars max="5" ng-model="reviewbusiness.rating"></input-stars>

                                    </ul>

                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Review Text</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" ng-model="reviewbusiness.review"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Leave a Review" />
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Angular controller

```
recentControllers.controller('BusinesspageController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
        $scope.id = $routeParams.itemId;

        $scope.reviewbusiness = {};
        $scope.add_review = function(){
            $scope.reviewbusiness.user_id = 1;
            $scope.reviewbusiness.business_id = 42;


            console.log($scope.reviewbusiness);
            //return;
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://ba.dev/reviewbusinesses/reviewbusinesses/',
                data: $scope.reviewbusiness,
                headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
  }

            })
                    .success( function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                    })
                    .error( function(response){
                       console.log(response); 
                    });
        };



    }]);
```

error i am getting

```
<h1>Error</h1>Couldn't create model <b>reviewbusinesses</b><ul><li>Attribute: user_id</li><ul><li>User cannot be blank.</li></ul><li>Attribute: business_id</li><ul><li>Business cannot be blank.</li></ul><li>Attribute: review</li><ul><li>Review cannot be blank.</li></ul><li>Attribute: rating</li><ul><li>Rating cannot be blank.</li></ul></ul>
```

When I use GET method.
[image: When I use GET method]
Response
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actionCreate in Yii seems use GET metho so don't eval the data that you submit by post method  ..

try using GET metodh in your ajax

```
       $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://ba.dev/reviewbusinesses/reviewbusinesses/',
            data: $scope.reviewbusiness,
            headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
}
```

Comment: see the image when i use GET method. it does not post the comment

Comment: sir when i use GET method just like you explained above the status is okay, when I check in inspect element->network, but it does not go in the database.

Comment: In response I am getting all the data from my model class REVIEWBUSINESS in the form of objects. see image 2

Comment: @UsmanIqbal  .....Well  this mean that your original question about error http  500 is solved  and you have eventually a new problem ,... then should fair mark my answer as accepted and post a new question for  the new problem ..